# How to limit a conditioned result query in PHP/MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, limit

I need to limit the first six results from a query with a condition WHERE.

I would like to do something like that:

```
mysql_query("CREATE VIEW [test] AS SELECT * FROM table WHERE status=1");

$sel = "SELECT * FROM [test] LIMIT 0,6";

$result = mysql_query($sel);

while($r=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
    echo "".$r['id']."<br>";
}
```

How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding the `WHERE` clause? There's nothing special, just put it before the `LIMIT`

Comment: I don't understand. What's the problem with `$sel = "SELECT * FROM [test] WHERE condition = value LIMIT 0,6";` ????

Comment: Simple as that. Actually I was having a problem in other part of my code. That's why the fetch_array wasn't working.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE this = 'that' ";
$limit = "ORDER BY index LIMIT 6 ";
$result = mysql_query($query.$limit);
```

You need to limit your ordered conditional selection. (You probably don't have to order this)

Comment: Simple as that. Actually I was having a problem in other part of my code. That's why the fetch_array wasn't working.

Thank you all.